# I'm getting "Error 1" when compiling libtcod in MinGW's Shell

Tags: c++, shell, compiler-errors, mingw, libtcod

I am currently installing libtcod for MinGW to make a roguelike and was following the instructions from the documentation on their website : http://doryen.eptalys.net/data/libtcod/doc/1.5.2/html2/compile_libtcod_mingw.html?c=true&cpp=true&cs=true&py=true&lua=true
Everything worked up to the compiling of libtcod (at the end) with...

```
make -f makefiles/makefile-mingw
```

...where I get an Error 1 on the file src\zlib\zutil.c. Here's a screenshot :
http://i855.photobucket.com/albums/ab112/maximemoring/error1.png

Does anyone know this problem and/or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So `off64_t` seems to be undefined. Based on [this thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-amd64/2009/05/msg00067.html), it sounds like compiling with `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` set may fix the problem. You can pass that define to the compiler by running make like so:

`make -f makefiles/makefile-mingw CPPFLAGS=-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1`

Comment: That didn't do it. I'm still getting that same error.  Adding that to zutil didn't work.
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE    1
#include <sys/types.h>

Comment: I'm going to try it for io.h

Comment: Nope that didn't do it either.